# Identify memory use

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, garbage-collection, profiling

My application has an in-memory cache which is eventually using lots of memory. I would like to quantify this. For that I have just run a memory [profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler), and I have obtained the following plot:

[image]

I was expecting memory use to go down when processing is complete, since I am cleaning the cache, but memory use remains constant long after processing has finished.

I have introduced a big artificial delay after cleaning the cache, and I have even forced [garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#module-gc) by calling `gc.collect()`, but nothing is helping.

How can I identify where is memory being used?

Comment: How are you acquiring that memory? Is it reproducible in a simple case?

Comment: @user1767754 By reading backend data, caching it, doing some complex processing, writing results to the intermediate cache, and finally, once the multiple rounds of processing have been performed, flushing the data to the backend. Not easy to reproduce at all.